# How to get parameter value from link in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `Firebase dynamic links` and I save it to a `deepLink` variable and pass it to the next page. Tell me, how can I get the `code` and `pageName` parameters from the link so that I can use them in the future?

**url**

```
https://.........app?pageName=emailActivationPage&code=7075
```

**code**

```
await Firebase.initializeApp();

  final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

if (widget.initialLink != null) {
      final Uri deepLink = widget.initialLink!.link;
      routeCubit.toForgotPasswordPage(deepLink.path, true);
    } else {
      routeCubit.toPhoneNumberPage();
      }
```

Comment: you can use autorouter library to generate routes and path and route names,
You can also parse the pageName from the link and manually check and navigate to that page

Comment: Is there a source to look at an implementation example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data through the queryParameter property. It also should be a good idea to check beforehand if the key is given in the Map

```
if(deepLink.queryParameters.containsKey('code')){
final code = deepLink.queryParameters['code'];
}
```

Comment: Does the code come in String format? I write that null, did you correctly indicate that this is how you can get the parameter?

Comment: Updated the answer it is queryParameters instead of queryParameter

Comment: Tell me, how can I check if the key is on the map?

Comment: I do as you showed, but apparently there is a null value, since nothing comes

Comment: Rather, the problem is that when I transfer data to another screen, it may be lost or I call deeplink incorrectly